# OpenMP different results 1 core vs multiple

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, multicore

I've been trying to make my program in C multicore the last few months, yet I keep getting this strange problem. Maybe some of you can help me out a little?

The problem I'm having is that my program gives proper results when I let it calculate using only one thread. However, when I choose more threads, my values start changing, even though the calculations performed should be exactly the same (aside of a random number generator, but this shouldn't be the issue as each core does have its own unique seeder and the generator is known to work with openmp multicore processing).

Anyway, as the program itself is kind of confidential, I cannot give you the entire code (it's way too large for convenient use anyway) so I'll try my best to give parts of the code, which may further explain the problem.

First the libraries I included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h> /* openmp header */
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h> /*RNG header*/
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h> /*RNG header*/
```

Then I define some structures etc, but I know these work as the program does work in single core mode. Then I have the main function, in which my openMP parallel loop looks like this:

```
 //perform multicore calculations (loop over all photons)
 #pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
   num_threads(thread_cnt) \
   private(icount,thread_id,i) \
   shared(calc,imstr,sum_irefl,leaks) \
   copyin(scat,cap,pcap_ini,profile,absmu,ctvar,lib)
 for(icount=0; icount <= cap.ndet; icount++){
   thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
   printf("\nthread %d scat:\n",thread_id);
   for(i=0;i<NDIM;i++) printf("%f\t",scat[i]);
   do{
     do{
       start(ctvar, absmu, profile, &pcap_ini, &cap, &icount, &imstr, &lib, calc, &thread_id); 
       do capil(ctvar, absmu, profile, &pcap_ini, &cap, &icount, &imstr, &lib, leaks, scat,
         calc, &thread_id);
       while (calc[thread_id].iesc == 0); /* perform capil until iesc not equal to 0 anymore */
       }
     while(calc[thread_id].iesc == -2); /* only do count etc if iesc!=-2, else redo start */
     count(absmu, ctvar, &cap, &icount, profile, leaks, &imstr,calc, &thread_id);
     }
   while(calc[thread_id].iesc == -3);
   sum_irefl[thread_id] = sum_irefl[thread_id] + calc[thread_id].i_refl;
   if(icount%1000 == 0 && thread_id == 0) printf("%d\t%ld\t%f\n",icount,calc[0].i_refl,
     calc[0].rh[2]);
   }
```

In these subfunctions ( `start, capil, count` ) some variables are written with new values, this is the case for `calc,imstr,sum_irefl` and `leaks`. I set them as shared, so each thread can access them. However, I don't believe there's a chance for a memory race as for instance `calc` is actually split up in an array, where each thread has its own variables (accessed through their unique `thread_id`) and the other shared variables may be raced to as they're not read at any point. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the dangers of memory races, but I don't think this poses a problem here...

The `copyin` variables were made threadsafe before (not shown here, but the compiler does not complain, so I assume it's not a problem) and they're only read during the parallel loop, so again I don't see what the problem could be.
Furthermore, I checked that each variable at the start of the parallel loop has the values it should have. So it's somewhere during the parallel section that values are obtained that are different when I run the program with 1 or more cores.

I know this is not a lot to go on, but I hope some of you have an idea nevertheless. If you need more information, do feel free to ask me, as I might be able to supply more.

So things that I wonder: could it be possible I have a harmful memory race after all? Do you see anything else that could be going wrong? Do you know of any (relatively) easy-to-use programs I could use to check my multicore program?

Comment: There is definitely something missing here.  Why are you getting and using a thread id in a parallel loop context? You are accessing the calc variable by something completely independent of the loop, is it merged somewhere later?  At the very least, this should be split into an omp parallel region, which gets the thread ID and does thread specific work, and an enclosed for worksharing construct which spreads the thread-independent work.

Comment: The calc variable is indeed merged after the parallel for loop.
I also think I understand your last remark, but the 'problem' is that during the for loop also thread specific work is done (for instance calc[thread_id].iesc gets a new value and such things). So the way I see it I cannot make the for loop thread independent.
But perhaps I'm misunderstanding you... could you write me a code example of the split up parallel and for region using the code I mentioned in my original question?

Comment: @user2257570 could you tell us which random number generator do you use? I am interested in generators to be used safely with openmp.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, the code would look something like this.  While the thread dependent values are still used in the loop, they don't have to be reinitialized every single pass through, which at the least will save you some overhead.  I'm still not sure I'm seeing where the problem is from your example though.  Are all of the shared variables only referenced by thread_id? You mention they are not read, but how are they updated, are you perhaps summing or otherwise accumulating values in them?

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) \
   num_threads(thread_cnt) \
   shared(calc,imstr,sum_irefl,leaks) \
   copyin(scat,cap,pcap_ini,profile,absmu,ctvar,lib)
{
 int icount, thread_id, i; //note, private by definition in the region
 thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
 printf("\nthread %d scat:\n",thread_id);
 //perform multicore calculations (loop over all photons)
 #pragma omp for
 for(icount=0; icount <= cap.ndet; icount++){

   for(i=0;i<NDIM;i++) printf("%f\t",scat[i]);
   do{
     do{
       start(ctvar, absmu, profile, &pcap_ini, &cap, &icount, &imstr, &lib, calc, &thread_id); 
       do capil(ctvar, absmu, profile, &pcap_ini, &cap, &icount, &imstr, &lib, leaks, scat,
         calc, &thread_id);
       while (calc[thread_id].iesc == 0); /* perform capil until iesc not equal to 0 anymore */
       }
     while(calc[thread_id].iesc == -2); /* only do count etc if iesc!=-2, else redo start */
     count(absmu, ctvar, &cap, &icount, profile, leaks, &imstr,calc, &thread_id);
     }
   while(calc[thread_id].iesc == -3);
   sum_irefl[thread_id] = sum_irefl[thread_id] + calc[thread_id].i_refl;
   if(icount%1000 == 0 && thread_id == 0) printf("%d\t%ld\t%f\n",icount,calc[0].i_refl,
     calc[0].rh[2]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! I thought you meant to do something like this, but wasn't sure ;)
You are also on the good track I think with the adding values... All shared variables are indeed summed or accumulated values in them during the for loop. Basically they are counters marking the occurance of certain events. Should I do something for this? I read something on a reduction clause which I might have to use, but I don't really understand it. Would you have any further advise, njustn? Thanks for the help this far!

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was returning from Germany.  Any accumulated variables need to be protected, the issue is that even a statement like foo++ is actually a read into a register, an add, then a write, which introduces data races.  To use the reduction clause, you will likely have to move the parallelism into the inner functions, which I doubt you want to do.  It may make more sense to create private copies of those, then combine them at the end as you already do the calc array.